# Doxygen: How to create extra class docs outside of source code?

Tags: documentation, markdown, doxygen

I'd like to add verbose information about my core classes without embedding it all above those classes in the source file.

For instance, I'd like to create a separate file with voluminous info about class `Foo`, probably in markdown or html.  Then when I view class `Foo` in the doxygen-created output, I'd like the class page for `Foo` to contain all my voluminous and beautifully marked up documentation in its details section along with any other comments I *did* put above class `Foo`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you currently have a file Foo.h

```
/**
A short description of class Foo.
*/
class Foo
{
}
```

You can add additional documentation in a file with a .dox extension (let's call it Foo.dox)

```
/**
More details about Foo.

Maybe you only want to distribute this to your nicer customers.

@class Foo Foo.h
*/
```

Don't forget to add the .dox file to the INPUT line of your configuration file

```
INPUT = \
Foo.h Foo.dox
```

Comment: Well that was easy after all. :) Thanks!

Comment: Another use case might be to allow public access to documentation source but not source code, so that consumers of your APIs can send pull requests that add descriptions and examples.

Comment: 1. Will this work for types, functions, constants, etc? Or is it just for classes? 2. If you specify the "namespace path" of a class, will it appear in the documentation or just be used to resolve the class you're referring to?